# vue js applying animate function on element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to apply `.animate` function on element in vuejs?

```
<aside v-transition v-if="toggleMenu">
  <a href="#">Haha</a>
  <a href="#">Nice</a>
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
</aside>
```

similar piece of js code looks like

```
if (toggleMenu) {
  $('aside').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 200);
}
```

I have tried binding `style` attribute,

```
<aside v-transition :style="{width: toggleMenu?'toggle':'200px'}">
```

but it fails to animate. I'm trying to achieve something like this https://codepen.io/grantimbo/pen/bmevz through vue.

Comment: Be sure to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317144/vue-js-applying-animate-function-on-element#50317144 also this is intresting: https://css-tricks.com/intro-to-vue-5-animations/

Comment: If you already know the above things,then the v-transition attribute it means that is a vue directive.And you have to know about directives.If not, then to use you jquery animation you have to add a class to aside tag

Comment: @roliroli Where I have to include the jquery animate code?

Comment: Here's an updated Code Pen using Vue JS to toggle a CSS class on the sidebar : https://codepen.io/officert/pen/JvZOoB

Comment: @officert thanks it;s working

Comment: No prob @AvinashRaj, I added an answer, if you could mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated Code Pen that uses Vue JS to toggle a CSS class on the sidebar :

https://codepen.io/officert/pen/JvZOoB

Here's the aside element:

```
<aside :class="{ 'open' : sidebarOpen }">
```

Here's the aside CSS:

```
aside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #383838;
  left: -300px;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 0.1s ease-in;
}
aside.open {
  left:0;
}
```

and here's the Vue component method that does the toggling:

```
toggleSidebar() {
  this.sidebarOpen = !this.sidebarOpen;
}
```